# Force inactivity lock on application that circumvents it

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, lock-screens

I have a game that disables inactivity lock on my phone as long as it is foreground (there's enough ways to do that if you look around on development SE sites). This is generally a good thing, since it have somewhat long-ish matches that can be set to autopilot and having to manually tap to prevent autolocking would be annoying.

However it is NOT fine when I set lock period in phone settings to half a hour, start playing before sleep and WANT it to go into lock if I actually fall asleep while playing! I don't want phone to stay at max heat all night because GPU and charger fight each other over energy flow.  I have an unrooted Lenovo A1000.

Application does not have any setting to disable this behavior. Is there a way I can enforce my lock period settings on any application so any time I don't actively touch any controls on phone for specified time, it goes into a lock, no matter if foreground application wants that or not?